Controlling individual app volume with hotkeys on Mac?
I looked at Soundsource and BackgroundMusic, and neither of them have hotkeys to increase or lower the volume of the current app (the app whose window is on-top / focused). Ideally I want to and see the volume level like you do when pressing the volume up and down keys.

Define "current app".  The app currently generating audio?  What if there's more than one?  Does "current" then mean the app that currently has focus?

I made an edit, yes its the one that has focus
